# How to disable passing properties between seda endpoints?

Tags: apache-camel

Using seda endpoints I see Exchange properties are passed between endpoints.
Example:

```
sedaRouteA.setProperty("myProperty", 1) -> sending ->  sedaRouteB.getProperty("myProperty")
```

In sedaRouteB I am able to read property which was set in sedaRouteA

How to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable that. You can manually remove these properties before sending to seda.